# What happens after a Motion to Vacate has been granted?

Tags: judging

What happens after a Motion to Vacate has been granted?

Let's consider an example.  Let's say that A and B had a custody dispute, and A won.  There was a court order that B had to pay $x more per month.

But now let's say B filed a motion to vacate (for a specific reason).  What happens if the motion to vacate is granted?  Does the case go back to be reconsidered, fresh?

Also, what is the noun that goes with the verb "to vacate"?